# Javascript: appendchild append div not working

Tags: javascript

i want to dynamically add div element to my page.searching around including Stackoverflow gives me this sample code:

```
var main = document.getElementById('MasterContainer'); //manually defined div with this id 
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute("id","container1");
main.appendChild(div);
```

note: its inside a document.ready function.

and the result does not contain container1 div.

Comment: just to confirm, do you have `MasterContainer` div element in your html? + as you have tagged the question to javascript, i guess you might haven't added jquery files to your page. Did you?

Comment: the code's fine, add in a `console.log()` to make sure it's being called. http://jsfiddle.net/Rv93C/ ... and maybe post more code / html

Comment: Yeah Dom Day is right, and his fiddle proves it. My question then becomes, how are you checking to see if the div is added? If your testing browser has an inspector (right click, "Inspect Element") see if that is showing it, because it sounds like you might be viewing source, which I believe in most browsers show the unmodified html.

Comment: ahh, you are right, i checked with Chrome browser view source which as you said show unmodified html source.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be fine, check if the element with id #MasterContaienr is on the page and the name has been write well

Comment: i checked that multiple times, the fact is if there is no MasterContainer appendchild will return an error but there is no error

Comment: @user1229351 try to open the chrome debugging console (F12) and throw " document.getElementById('MasterContainer'); ". Look what comes out